# Getting error while adding image of product to cart using RSET API

Tags: magento2, addtocart, rest-api

I am facing one issue. I am adding configurable product to cart with its image,size and color but getting the below error using magento-2 REST API.

> Error:

```
{"message":"The image content must be valid base64 encoded data."}
```

I am adding my code below.

```
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
$psku=$_POST['sku'];
$qty=$_POST['quantity'];
$isConfigurable=$_POST['isConfigurable'];
$image=$_POST['image_url'];
$image_id=$_POST['image_id'];
$escaped_url=str_replace( '\/', '/', $image);
$type = pathinfo($escaped_url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($escaped_url);
$base64=base64_encode($escaped_url);
$itype='image/'.$type;
//$itype=str_replace( '\/', '/',$itype);
//echo $itype;exit;
$iname=basename($escaped_url);
//echo $base64;exit;
if ($isConfigurable==1) {
    if (isset($_POST['size_attribute_value'])) {
        $size_attribute_value=$_POST['size_attribute_value'];
    }else{
        $size_attribute_value='';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['size_attribute_id'])) {
        $size_attribute_id=$_POST['size_attribute_id'];
    }else{
        $size_attribute_id='';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['color_attribute_value'])) {
        $color_attribute_value=$_POST['color_attribute_value'];
    }else{
        $color_attribute_value='';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['color_attribute_id'])) {
        $color_attribute_id=$_POST['color_attribute_id'];
    }else{
        $color_attribute_id='';
    }
}
if ($isConfigurable==1) {
            $ettr=array();
            $citems=array(array("option_id"=>$size_attribute_id,"option_value"=>$size_attribute_value),array("option_id"=>$color_attribute_id,"option_value"=>$color_attribute_value),array("option_id"=>$image_id,"option_value"=>"file","extension_attributes"=>array("file_info"=>array("base64_encoded_data"=>$base64,"type"=>$itype,"name"=>$iname))));
            //$poption=array("extension_attributes"=>array("configurable_item_options"=>$citems));
            $poption=array("extension_attributes"=>array("custom_options"=>$citems));
            $item=array("quote_id"=>$quote,"sku"=>$psku,"qty"=>$qty,"product_option"=>$poption);
            $cartData=array("cartItem"=>$item);
        }else{
            $citems=array(array("option_id"=>$image_id,"option_value"=>"file","extension_attributes"=>array("file_info"=>array("base64_encoded_data"=>$base64,"type"=>$itype,"name"=>$iname))));
            $poption=array("extension_attributes"=>array("custom_options"=>$citems));
            $item=array("quote_id"=>$quote,"sku"=>$psku,"qty"=>$qty,"product_option"=>$poption);
            $cartData=array("cartItem"=>$item);
        }
        //echo json_encode($cartData);exit;
        $requestUrl ='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/items';
        $ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($cartData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token1)));
        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        //print_r($result);exit;
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($result), True);
        echo json_encode($array);exit;
```

My json format boy input are like below.

```
{"cartItem":{"quote_id":"202","sku":"KB067","qty":"1","product_option":{"extension_attributes":{"custom_options":[{"option_id":"225","option_value":"175"},{"option_id":"93","option_value":"163"},{"option_id":"147","option_value":"file","extension_attributes":{"file_info":{"base64_encoded_data":"aHR0cDovL21hZ2VudG8tMTQ4NDg2LTQyNTc3NS5jbG91ZHdheXNhcHBzLmNvbS9wdWIvbWVkaWEvY2F0YWxvZy9wcm9kdWN0Ly8xLzEvMTEuanBlZw==","type":"image\/jpeg","name":"11.jpeg"}}}]}}}}
```

Here I am giving the full path of image(`i.e-http:\/\/example.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/\/1\/1\/11.jpeg`) and its id as input. Please help me to resolve this error.